# complex rounding decimals in excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel, formula

Have created formula for example `=(E2+(G2*37))/290` which returns decimals based on data entered but can't work out how to round the answer to get the following:

1. `If 0 to 0.39 round to 0`
2. `If 0.4 to 0.89 round to 0.5`
3. `If 0.9 to 1.39 round to 1`
4. `If 1.4 to 1.89 round to 1.5`
5. `If 1.9 to 2.39 round to 2 etc`

Hope my question makes sense.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your custom rounding is simply rounding to the nearest 0.5.....but with an "offset" of 0.15. With value to be rounded in A1 you can do that with a simple formula, i.e.

`=ROUND(A1*2-0.3,0)/2`

or with your calculation in place of A1 that becomes

`=ROUND((E2+G2*37)/290*2-0.3,0)/2`

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit convoluted but this should work:

```
=IF(A1 + 0.1 - ROUNDDOWN(A1+0.1;0) < 0.5; ROUNDDOWN(A1+0.1;0); ROUNDDOWN(A1+0.1;0) + 0.5)
```

where `A1` is the cell you want to round.

e.g.
[image]

**N.B.**

- This works only for positive numbers.
- Ranges are actually:
  `[0, 0.39999999...] [0.4 , 0.8999999...] ...`
  or equally:
  `[0, 0.4) [0.4 , 0.9) ...`

Answer (score 0):

You could define a VBA function to do this for you:

```
Public Function CustomRound(number As Double)
    Dim result As Double, fraction As Double

    fraction = number - Int(number)

    If number <= 0.39 Then
        result = 0
    ElseIf fraction >= 0.4 And fraction <= 0.9 Then
        result = Int(number) + 0.5
    Else
        result = Round(number, 0)
    End If

    CustomRound = result
End Function
```

You would call this as follows:

```
=CustomRound((E2+(G2*37))/290)
```

Example:

```
=CustomRound(0.23) // 0
=CustomRound(1.58) //1.5
=CustomRound(2.12) //2
```

Comment: Thankyou thankyou thankyou - VBA function worked brilliantly.

Comment: @Fazette - no problem. If you are happy could you accept the answer by clicking the tick mark? That way other users who have similar issues can be confident the solution will work for them too.